# if slightly tilt the ios device, sfcombobox scrolled up to top in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

if slightly tilt the ios device, sfcombobox scrolled up to the top in xamarin.forms.it is occurring while the first time we entering to the page.

```
<combobox:SfComboBox DataSource="{Binding SamplePickerList, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SamplePickerIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" SelectedItem="{Binding SamplePicker,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by using SfComboBox Renderer and get the device rotation and UITableView content offset position. You can easily grab the exact offset of the table view by looking at its ContentOffset property.

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/ComboBox_ScrollResetRotating-1020669557

Code Snippet:

```
public class CustomComboBoxRenderer : SfComboBoxRenderer
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Find device rotation.
       /// </summary>
       UIDeviceOrientation orientation;
      public CustomComboBoxRenderer()
      {
             Foundation.NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(new NSString("UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification"), this.DeviceRotated);
      }
      private async void DeviceRotated(NSNotification obj)
      {
            if (this.Control.Text == string.Empty && this.Control.IsSuggestionOpen)
            {
                //// Get the table view position.
                var offset = this.Control.AutoCompleteTableView.TableView.ContentOffset;
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1);
                //// Set the table view position while rotating.
                this.Control.AutoCompleteTableView.TableView.ContentOffset = offset;
            }
     }
}
```

In this sample we are save the scroll position before the rotation using UIDeviceOrientation and then scroll to that row after the device tilt.

Comment: This will you an error when control is null.  if u check like below will working fine.
   if (this.Control != null  &&  this.Control.Text == string.Empty && this.Control.IsSuggestionOpen)

Comment: Yes. You can check the whether the control is null or not as per your previous update.